# Dynamically generating check boxes in php

Tags: php

I have two(2) tables **tblPermission** and **tblSubPermission** which holds the permissions of the user.
I wanted to create an interface like this

[image: Example Image]

the problem is I am stuck with my reference code *(please see reference code below)*. Like in the image the title of each column should be the main permissions (`tblPermission`) and the check boxes are the sub permissions(`tblSubPermission`).

Here is my database structure:

```
tblPermission (
    PermissionID NVARCHAR
    PremissionDesc NVARCHAR
)

tblSubPermission (
    SubPermissionID NVARCHAR
    PermissionID NVARCHAR
    SubPremissionDesc NVARCHAR
)
```

Here is my reference code from my previous project that generates check boxes and arranged them by columns. See this as example

[image]

The checkbox should be organized with the main permission.

```
$counter = 0;
$column = '';

if(!empty($righttype)){
    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT RightID, RightDescription FROM tblRight WHERE RightType = :righttype ORDER BY LENGTH(RightID), RightID');
    $sql->bindValue(':righttype', $righttype);
}
else{
    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT RightID, RightDescription FROM tblRight ORDER BY LENGTH(RightID), RightID');
}

if($sql->execute()){
    $count = $sql->rowCount();
    $fetchall = $sql->fetchAll();
    $range = range(1, $count);
    
    if(count($range) > 0){
        $divideCount = ceil(count($range)/2);
        $results = array_chunk($fetchall ,$divideCount);

        foreach($results as $result){
            $column .= '<div class="col-lg-6">';

            foreach($result as $fetchall){
                $counter++;
                
                $rightid = $fetchall['RightID'];
                $rightdesc = $fetchall['RightDescription'];
                $class = "right";
                    
                $column .= '<div class="col-lg-auto">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input right-checkbox '. $class .'" id="'. $rightid .'" value="'. $rightid .'">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="'. $rightid .'">'. $rightdesc .'</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
            }
                         
            $column .= '</div>';
        }

        return $column;
    }
}
else{
    return $sql->errorInfo();
}
```

Comment: Join the two tables and order the results by `PermissionDesc, SubPermissionDesc`. Whenever `PermissionDesc` changes, write a new heading. Then write `SubPermissionDesc` after the checkbox.

Comment: @Barmar the problem is there will be multiple permissiondesc if you join the two table or am I interpreting this wrong? can you show me your sample query?

Comment: That's why you only show the header when PermissionDesc changes, not every time through the loop.

Comment: `SELECT PermissionDesc, SubPermissionDesc from tblPermission p JOIN tblSubPermission sp ON p.PermissionID = sp.PermissionID ORDER BY PermissionDesc, SubPermissionDesc`.

Comment: You save PermissionDesc in a variable. Then when processing the next row you check if `$row['PermissionDesc'] != $last_permissionDesc`

Comment: @Barmar Can you show me the code? I do not know how can I store the PermissionDesc to $last_permissionDesc

Comment: Did you even think about it? `$last_permissionDesc = $row['PermissionDesc'];`

Comment: @Barmar yes but is it the same with `$row['PermissionDesc'] != $row['PermissionDesc'];`?

Comment: You assign it AFTER you do the check, of course.

Comment: See the code in the linked question.